# reducer function is not calling after action is triggered in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have two click handlers (industryClickHandler and companyClickHandler) which are populated using a loop in parent.js. i.e.

```
    renderListing() {
        if (this.props.data && this.props.data.listingDetails) {
          const listing = this.props.data.listingDetails.map(function(list, index) {
            return (
              <Listing
                key={index}
                id={list.id}
                title={list.title}
                industryClickHandler={() => {
                  return this.getCompanies({
                    industryName: list.title
                  });
                }}
                companyClickHandler={() => {
                  return this.getDepartments({
                    companyName: list.title,
                    companyId: list.id
                  });
                }}
              />
            );
          }, this);
          return listing;
        }
        return null;
      }


getCompanies(industryCreden) {
    this.props.dispatch(
      getIndustryData(industryCreden, this.props.callGraphQL)
    );
  }

  getDepartments(companyCreden) {
    this.props.dispatch(getCompanyData(companyCreden, this.props.callGraphQL));
  }
```

child.js

```
<a href="javascript:;"
        size={3}
        className="md-paper md-paper--2"
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={() => {
          switch (this.props.dataLogType) {
            case "industry":
              console.log("DatalogType: ", this.props.dataLogType);
              this.props.industryClickHandler();
              break;
            case "company":
              console.log("DatalogType: ", this.props.dataLogType);
              this.props.companyClickHandler();
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }}
      >
```

reducer.js

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case GET_RECRUITMENT_INDUSTRY_DATA:
...//CALLING CORRECTLY
case GET_RECRUITMENT_COMPANY_DATA:
...//NOT CALLING AT ALL
}
}
```

action.js

```
export const getIndustryData = (data, callGraphql) => {
  return {
    type: GET_RECRUITMENT_INDUSTRY_DATA,
    payload: data
  };
};

export const getCompanyData = (data, callGraphql) => {
  console.log("GET_RECRUITMENT_COMPANY_DATA in action called and data: ", data);
  return {
    type: GET_RECRUITMENT_COMPANY_DATA,
    payload: data
  };
};
```

Actually, industryClickHandler  is working fine and calling the correct REDUCER SWITCH CASE but the companyCLickHandler is not calling it's own reducer switch case.

Similarly, I have examined closely through REDUX_DEV_TOOL and also through REDUX_LOGGER and the state is also of my needs. I have consoled both of the click handlers and both reach the ACTIONS (or ACTION CREATORS) But, the industryClickHandler is dispatching exact redux reducer switch statement but companyCli8ckHandler is not doing so.

I have used mapDispatchToProps correctly as well.

Do anyone know which should be the issue that; one is calling correct reducer and the other is not calling correct switch case. Thanks

FROM CONSOLE:
GET_RECRUITMENT_COMPANY_DATA in actions is working and getting reponse from graphql as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Please post your action and reducer javascript file as well. Those are needed for any debugging help.

Comment: both are different as can be seen as serving different purposes.

Comment: I have simplified code i.e. i have removed internal logics for better understanding

Comment: I don't see either of your actions calling the thunk middleware (I'm assuming your doing a graphQL call somewhere). Could be one of the calls to graphQL is failing. Have you added debug in those methods?

Comment: Yes , I am calling graphql and data is coming in response just like the first one. Please, check the image i am uploading.

Comment: is `callGraphql` a function ? ...and is there a `catch()` there so that u'll know if the call failed ?

Comment: All the logs in the image are shown , are coming from the ACTION file. I then pass the response to as a PAYLOAD to the REDUCER. It is redux principle.

Comment: yes, callGraphql is a function and it is getting data correctly. It is actually a PROMISE. All stuffs are coming correctly till Action but lost when come to reducer and is not calling the intended switch case. I am wondering what's wrong with it.

Comment: I wonder why most people here on Stackoverflow are only DOWNVOTING. What's wrong with my question? Any reason ? Downvoter, what you say?

Comment: Everything seems correct with your code. I would however like to see how you are are importing the actionTypes in reducer and where have you exported it. Could be a problem there